# Difference between two values for a specific value in another coloumn

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have table with the profile IDs of people and the Date: the last time they accessed their online profile.

```
   Profile      Date      
     1108      2015-01-19        
     1108      2014-06-27     
     1108      2016-09-13
     1284      2015-03-04       
     1284      2015-06-21
     1641      2016-07-14
```

I would like to create two new variables:

1. that shows the "number of days since their first visit". So basically, the present date minus the first date (earliest date) of visit. And if the data is for the first visit by a profile, the days should result as 0. For example profile ID 1108's earliest visit is 2014-06-27, therefore the new variable will be 0 for this. The second visit is on 2015-01-19. So the new variable will be number of days between 2015-01-19 and first visit. Similarly, for the third visit, the new variable will have the number of days between the third visit and the first visit
2. the visit count i.e. is it the first visit or the second. The earliest date will be the first visit, the next date the second and so on.

The resulting table should look like this:

```
   Profile      Date             Days           Vist_Count
     1108      2015-01-19        206                2
     1108      2014-06-27         0                 1
     1108      2016-09-13        809                3
     1284      2015-03-04         0                 1
     1284      2015-06-21        109                2
     1641      2016-07-14         0                 1
```

I hope i was clear about the question. Many thanks!
Wasiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'Profile', get the difference of 'Date' with `min` of 'Date' to create 'Days' column, while 'Visit_Count' is created by taking the `rank` of 'Date'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, `:=`(Days = Date - min(Date), Visit_Count = rank(Date)), Profile]
df1
#   Profile       Date     Days Visit_Count
#1:    1108 2015-01-19 206 days           2
#2:    1108 2014-06-27   0 days           1
#3:    1108 2016-09-13 809 days           3
#4:    1284 2015-03-04   0 days           1
#5:    1284 2015-06-21 109 days           2
#6:    1641 2016-07-14   0 days           1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Profile) %>%
    mutate(Days = Date - min(Date), Visit_Count = rank(Date))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Profile = c(1108L, 1108L, 1108L, 1284L, 1284L, 
1641L), Date = structure(c(16454, 16248, 17057, 16498, 16607, 
16996), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Profile", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```